# how to set selected row Foreground in uwp communitytoolkit datagrid Winui/UWP?

Tags: xaml, datagrid, winui-3

I want to change selected row Foreground in my Winui DataGrid , Seems there is no option to set it .

Comment: Is it WinUI3 or UWP + WinUI 2.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DataGrid`'s `SelectionChanged` event:

```cs
private SolidColorBrush DataGridRowSelectedForegroundBrush { get; set; } = new(Colors.LightGreen);

private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        return;
    }

    // DataGridRow has an "IsSelected" property but it's internal.
    // We can use Reflection to get this property.
    Type dataGridRowType = typeof(DataGridRow);
    PropertyInfo? isSelectedProperty = dataGridRowType.GetProperty("IsSelected", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (DataGridRow dataGridRow in dataGrid.FindDescendants().OfType<DataGridRow>())
    {
        if (isSelectedProperty?.GetValue(dataGridRow) is bool isSelected &&
            isSelected is true)
        {
            dataGridRow.Foreground = DataGridRowSelectedForegroundBrush;
            continue;
        }

        dataGridRow.Foreground = dataGrid.Foreground;
    }
}
```

BTW, I'm using the **CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI** NuGet package to use `FindDescendants()`.

Comment: Just so you know, I did try making this work with `VisualStates` but it turned out to be harder and more complicated than the code in my answer.